# How to list all the instances where the names in the fields are 4 letters only?

Tags: mysql, sql

List all names of employees who have 4 letters only in their names.

Im using livesql btw since i didnt know how to set up a server after downloading mysql. im using the emp table provided at lviesql.com
Im currently preparing for a SQL test and came across this question while revising. The question is "List all names of employees who have 4 letters". I dont know how to apply the LIKE "%" thingy to this. I tried "____%" but i got an error message in return. How do I need to write my query?

```
select *
from emp
where ENAME LIKE "____%"
```

The error message is ORA-00904: "____%": invalid identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use single quotes.  Second, if you want exactly 4 *characters* then remove the `'%'`.

```
select *
from emp
where ENAME LIKE '____'
```

Your version gets at least four characters.

If you specifically want four letters, use regular expressions:

```
where regexp_like(ENAME, '^[[:alpha:]]{4}$')
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ORA-nnnn` error message indicates that you are using oracle, not mysql as you tagged.

In Oracle, you can get the length of a string (in characters, not bytes) with function `LENGTH()`:

```
select * from emp where LENGTH(ename) = 4
```

Note: that condition that you were using (`ENAME LIKE "____%"`) actually checks for names that have *at least* 4 characters, not *exactly* 4 characters. If you want this in oracle then:

```
select * from emp where LENGTH(ename) >= 4
```

Comment: But this is a MySQL question, as tagged.

Comment: no i was using oracle because as a sub for my sql since i coudnt get it installed.

Comment: Oracle owns MySQL, so sometimes the error codes start with `ORA-` ... but it's not Oracle :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: really?!

Comment: alright but im like learning from a sql course. alright ill remove the tags and delete the question if thats not possible , sorry for the incoveniences caused

Comment: oh now that i reread your reply. i completely misunderstood your reply lol. sorry again.